How can I upload files to Teams sharepoint channels based on Filenames?
I want to be able to upload files to Teams Sharepoint sites via PowerAutomate/Python or something similar.
E.g.
BlueA1.xlsx is uploaded to the Blue Teams Channel www.sharepoint.com/Bluechannel
BlueA2.xlsx is uploaded to the Blue Teams Channel www.sharepoint.com/Bluechannel
RedA1.xlsx is uploaded to the Blue Teams Channel www.sharepoint.com/Redchannel
RedA2.xlsx is uploaded to the Blue Teams Channel www.sharepoint.com/Redchannel
I have my Powerautomate all linked with the appropriate Teams Sharepoint channels but I am not sure where to start
Here is a screenshot of what I have tried to make but I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

